# Multiple used work item in Prod Branch Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops

I am very newbie about azure devops . I want to control work item about adding pull request in prod brach. İf one item used before in prod release , developers  can not add this work item in Pull request any branch . But I could not find any thing about that for azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction to add a work item to a pull request again. As a simple explanation, your bug may regress at any time and you revert it to the "Active" state then add some additional fixes and create a new pull request linked to your regression bug.